# AFNetworking setting the right url path not working, Objective C

Tags: python, ios, objective-c, python-2.7, afnetworking

I use this code to make a post request in Objective C

```
NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.147:5000/test"];
    
    
    //static NSString *test = @"http://192.168.1.147:5000/test";
    UIWindow *window = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    UIView *topView = window.rootViewController.view;
    

    
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] initWithBaseURL:baseURL];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [manager POST:@"/" parameters:eventInfoObject success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject) {
    ....
```

And i have these two functions in Python that uses Flask:

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET'])
def hello():

@app.route("/test", methods=['POST'])
def addEvent():
```

Using Charles to see whats happening this is what is get when trying to use the code in Objective-C:

[image]

As you can see the URL is not /test also it says 405 METHOD NOT ALLOWED meaning it is being directed the the first method in Python that only allows GET requests. Why is it not being directed to addEvent() function?

Comment: Is `manager POST:@"/"` intentional, or did you mean to do `manager POST:@"/test"`?

Comment: I can swear that i tried that before but it did not work. Now it suddenly does. Thank you... @IanMacDonald